# does fprintf write '\0' in to the file if I write a string?

Tags: c++

I wrote the below code to understand file operations.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("c:\\te_st.txt", "w+");

    fprintf(fp, "aa");

    char *buf = new char[4];

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    int bytes = fscanf(fp, "%s", buf);

    cout << bytes << " " << buf << endl;

    fclose(fp);

    delete buf;

    return 0;
}
```

I got the doubt whether fprintf() writes characters 'a', 'a' and '\0' or 'a' and 'a'. When I print the output after reading from the file using fscanf, "aa" got displayed. But when I use fread() to read bytes from file as below,

```
fread(buf, 3, 1, fp);
```

"aa" and some junk characters are getting displayed. Can anyone please let me know what is the difference?

Comment: Then please show the code that used `fread` because it probably had a bug.  The terminating NUL byte is not written.

Comment: How do you request fread() to read 1 element of 3-bytes length from the file to which you wrote only 2 bytes? Furthermore, it would be more logical to call fread with size=1 and count=2: `fread(buf, 1, 2, fp)` , see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/

Comment: Run a simple test. Use `fprintf()` to write "aa" in a new file, close the file then check its size in the command prompt or using the file manager/explorer of your preference. The file size tells you the truth. Open the file using `fopen(""c:\\te_st.txt", "w")` (without `+`) or better delete the file before running the program, just to be sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> does fprintf write '\0' in to the file if I write a string?

No.
The code below writes "aa" into the file.

```
FILE *fp = fopen("c:\\te_st.txt", "w+");

    fprintf(fp, "aa");
```

When we look at the file in hex mode, we see that it has not printed any null terminator:

```
6161
```

Answer (score 3):

The question, I think, is simply whether `fprintf()` sends to the file the `NUL` (`\0` or zero) that all C strings end with. The answer is no, no terminating `NUL` is sent to the file.

Moreover, it is not possible to write a `NUL` to a file with `fprintf()` as the `NUL` will indicate the end of the string. To write a `NUL` you must use `fwrite()` (with buffered `FILE *` I/O) or `write` (with an fd).

Answer (score 1):

When calling fopen you must specify whether you are opening a file as text or binary:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("c:\\te_st.txt", "w+t"); // open text
FILE *fp = fopen("c:\\te_st.txt", "w+b"); // open binary
```

`fprintf`() and `fscanf`() functions are for text files.
`fwrite`() and `fread`() functions are for binary files.
When reading with `fread`() it is your responsibility to insert the terminating 0 into the buffer. `fread`() returns the number of elements read from the file, so if you call it with parameter `size=1`, and the value returned is positive, then that value can be used as the position to insert 0 at in the buffer.

Example for `fread()`:

```
int nRead = fread(buf, 1, 2, fp);
if(nRead > 0)
{
  buf[nRead] = 0;
  cout << buf << endl;
}
```

Comment: The main difference between `fread` / `fwrite` and `fprintf` / `fscanf` is that the former pair do not format / parse things, whereas the latter pair do format / parse things. I'm not sure it's a lot to do with binary modes (given on UNIX binary modes do nothing different AFAIK)

Comment: Well, using `fprintf`/`fscanf` for a binary file is probably not a good idea, though. Using `fread`/`/fwrite` for a text file might be right in some cases. (For example, if you want to read the entire file in one go.)